# Detect Category ID=4 in Joomla and show div

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I would like to detect a certain category with ID=4 and then apply if/else to add div to display contents.

```
<?php 
    if (JRequest::getVar('view')=='categories' && JRequest::getVar('id')==4) { ?>
<?php } ?>
```

How do I achieve this? 
I want to show this  if the article belongs to category 4 else show another div.

Imagining this two be the different div

```
<div class="category4">text here</div>
<div class="categoryxxx">text here</div>
```

Do note that `<?php echo $this->item->catid;?>` shows the correct Category ID. I would like to apply if and else statement using catid==9 or something. Just not good at PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also put directly the html code, avoiding `echo`. It may useful especially when html code is sizeable.

```
<?php if ($this->item->catid == 4): ?>

<div class="category4">text here</div>
<!--- any other html code --->

<?php else: ?>

<div class="categoryxxx">text here</div>
<!--- any other html code --->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey I got it working :)

```
<?php
if ($this->item->catid == 9) { 
    echo "yes, it exists"; 
    } 
    else { 
    echo "no, it don't exist"; 
    }
?>
```